# Where are the symbols yy_switch_to_buffer and yy_create_buffer defined?

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to build a project that uses **flex** and at link time the following flex symbols are undefined: `yy_create_buffer` and `yy_switch_to_buffer`. These are clearly flex functions as documented in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html).

Do you have any idea where these functions are defined? I suspect they are from a flex library should be passed to linker... However, I have searched the latest flex, flex-devel packages for my distribution (redhat) and there does not seem to be any such library.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols would be in the output of `flex`, not in a library.  They are defined in the skeleton (which `flex` expands with `m4`).  If you are having linkage problems with these symbols, the problem could be due to mis-definition of the referencing code:

- the skeleton can generate C or C++ code; in the latter case the class name is needed to link to it, e.g., `yyFlexLexer::yy_create_buffer`
- the leading `yy` can be altered through command-line option of `flex` to change the prefix.  Your build-scripts may overlook providing this option when compiling some file.

Comment: There was a mistake in the makefile and the build process was using *lex* instead of *flex*. Although lex/flex have a similar syntax and API, lex does not support switching the input buffers and hence the two undefined symbols. Thanks for the hint.